# How do you use the output of a terraform apply as input into another terraform variable?

Tags: terraform, azure-policy

Policy as code - Azure - Terraform
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/policy_definition

The output is an id. This id needs to be used as a variable for a policy assignment.
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/resource_group_policy_assignment

1. How is this written in terraform?
2. Does the terraform apply need to be separate for each definition and assignment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply pass the `azurerm_policy_definition` output to resource `azurerm_resource_group_policy_assignment` like in the example you find in the [DOC](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/resource_group_policy_assignment#example-usage)

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group_policy_assignment" "example" {
  name                 = "example"
  resource_group_id    = azurerm_resource_group.example.id
  policy_definition_id = azurerm_policy_definition.example.id # This is the output of azurerm_policy_definition resource

  ...
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are just starting with Terraform, but it's very easy to pass output of one resource to another and Terraform will make sure to deploy policy_definition before resource_group_policy_Assignment.

Assuming the name of the block is called policy as shown in terraform website.
The reference in policy assignment to the ID will look like-
azurerm_policy_definition.policy.id

Please read on the documentation in terraform for reference resources.
https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/references#resources
https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/references#references-to-resource-attributes